# AndroidOS draining battery massively on Android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery, asus-zenfone-2

I have an ASUS Zenfone 2 with Android version 5.0. All of a sudden today it started draining the battery rapidly.

- I have made multiple restarts but it didn't help.
- I tried to scan the phone with Norton and Kaspersky to identify any possible risks, but got nothing.
- I uninstalled all latest apps that I installed in previous few days.

Even while it is connected to a power source, it is still not able to increase the battery charge level. I know according to the usage battery consumption can be high but only Wi-Fi is running and I'm not using the phone. And 115% usage is really very high.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Related: [What can cause "Android OS" process to use high percentage of battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12347) / [How can I find out what causes "Android OS" to consume battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17382)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd look for is ***one app*** that's using an extraordinary amount of resources.

Go to settings>apps> [choose an app -- I'd start with Chrome or any other browser that you use]

Then do a "Force Stop" on the suspected app.  See if that helps.  If there are any apps that you rarely use you can keep them stopped -- so you know they aren't using any battery.

It could be a hardware problem.

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with your phone but have used 5.0 quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had such a problem, it was not because of how the battery was emptied, but how it was charged.

I bought a new usb cable and everything was fine again :)
Don't ask me why though!

Comment: Can you explain it a little further.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a Greenify app to hibernate an aplications: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=pl

Comment: That doesn't explain why AndroidOS is causing huge battery drain. Please follow [How do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)